# Comfortable way of entering and exiting Airships anywhere at will

Tags: airships

Imagine that the taboo around Airships and dirigibles is broken. Besides some cargo, passenger and tourism Airships there's one company that focuses on the super-rich by selling what are essentially flying super-yachts.

A metamaterial skin prevents the gas from escaping the hull, meaning you'll lose maybe 1% of your gas per year. Electricity is created through pressure, wind, batteries, a backup engine and solar panels on the outer shell (mainly semi-rigid or rigid [Airships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airship) are used I assume). Water can be collected and filtered for use both from rain or by collecting from the sea/lakes. An on-board computer accessible from anywhere in the ship keeps it level, can steer the ship to any destination while avoiding obstacles and it monitors the local weather and news reports to keep the airship safe from hazardous weather conditions (rule of thumb: Any weather with winds faster than the Airships max speed is dangerous). And similar to [Airships of old](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Akron_(ZRS-4)) it can reach a whopping 130km/h.

Now most problems that would arise can be handwaved away with future materials or for the most part existing solutions and real-life Airships already exist that can do what I want. But what I cant figure out is how to make these Airships comfortable to enter and exit. You want whoever from your small crew to be able to get out and get the groceries or maintenance parts without the need to stop where you are going. But more importantly you want to get in your supercar and be safely on the ground or return to the airship with minimal discomfort and minimal facilities. So far the only solution I have thought off is an extendable elevator at the bottom of the airship and a parking lot. But that still means you need a pretty damn long extendable arm on your elevator to reach the ground if you are anywhere near houses or worse some flats. It also means your crew wont be able to leave without stopping the airship.

Anyone got any bright ideas?

Criteria on which the solutions will be judged:
- Passenger/storage capacity.

- comfort (less effort in a more natural position = more comfort in general)
- Overhead (=minimum preparation time to use the solution. Having to strap on a parachute has a higher overhead than stepping in a flight-ready helicopter).
- average speed
- Average distance it can reach.
- Service time between uses, including potential refueling.
- Ground facilities required to use the solution. In some cases the size of the area required to for example land would need to be mentioned as a ground facility as well.

Edit: this is not an all-airship future or a steampunk setting. Airships would simply supplement current transport options. And just like all other transport before it, the rest wouldnt become obsolete.

Comment: There's no taboo, they're just not very good when compared to the other options.

Comment: Comfortable is a matter of opinion. Some people do like parachuting for quick exits.

Comment: How to safely load and unload an airship has *always* been one of the biggest problems. Most airship disasters, and the many associated deaths, have happened near the landing field.

Comment: @separatix people think Airships are loud, exceedingly slow, made of explodium and crash when you sneeze too hard. Consider that despite few companies building them they cost about 12 to 15 million (about the same as a 6-car train) and that most startups have handled it badly. As if you found some new (or old) tech and try to build a smartphone rivalling the current best while you had no prior experience in making them. I think there are markets for them and that their cost/effectiveness can be good enough to compete with existing transport.

Comment: @Renan how are you going to parachute up the airship paragliding would work in a way, but it would be risky and time consuming. Comfort in general means as little effort as possible with a low-effort posture. Like in a chair. And that chair is deemed more comfortable in general if its softer and more supportive etc.

Comment: I think a common misconception is how small the pilot/passenger compartment of a blimp is. A normal blimp that you may see today, it's about the size of an internal of a car. Makes this question weird to answer.

Comment: @Andrey its an airship. Blimps are Airships, but not all Airships are Blimps. Rigid Airships for example allow compartments to be build in the "baloon" part as the gas is inside compartimentalized cells throughout the ship.

Comment: @user535733 modern Airships already need a lot less. Many dont even need to be moored down to unload its passengers/cargo. Otherwise yes, this is the question I am hoping to answer.

Comment: They are slow, noise depends on technologies, they're highly vulnerable to adverse weather conditions, and their cargo capacity is tiny relative to their bulk. The fastest airship crossing of the Atlantic is 71 hours, the fastest [passenger ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_United_States) crossing is 82 hours.

Comment: @Demigan i am trying to say that to have living space the size of yacht the lighter than air sections would need to be the size of a stadium.

Comment: "made of explodium" only if filled with Hydrogen.  Even then they would tend to burn, rather than explode.

Comment: If you live on an airship you don't do your own shopping....

Comment: @Andrey I havent found (or looked very well yet) any data for the compartments vs cell density yet. If you have some to get an idea what size the rigid/semi-rigid Airships would need to be it would be wonderful.

Comment: @Baldrickk that was the point yes. Airships are ridiculously durable even when filler with Hyrdogen. From what I read almost all airship disasters were man made errors, such as becoming overconfident in bad weather and being blown against a mountainside. Modern Airships seem to share the same relationship with their ancient counterparts as an early biplane with a modern jet airliner.

Comment: @Mazura thats why you want the crew to be able to get it for you with minimal disturbance in where you want to go.

Comment: Wind only matters when you are near the ground.  Otherwise, you are traveling with the wind.  Unless the engines are running, those in or on the airship won't experience any wind.  What will get you is turbulence (where winds of different vectors interact).  Also, near the ground up and down drafts.  If are in cumulus clouds or, worse, thunder clouds, you will be in for an exciting ride.

Comment: @separatrix they are less noisy than any other aircraft. for example the Airlander has a few 50KW engines while a single bus engine has 115 to 240KW (Mercedes benz bus engine and this site:
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_Air_Vehicles_HAV_304/Airlander_10).  So it cant be much louder than a bus, which is an improvement over a helicopter. Also this Airlander is capable of 148km/h. The Graf Zeppelin did 117km/h cruising and 128km/h max speed. While that passenger ship does 65km/h max. Comparing the old Airships to modern one's is like a propengine compared to a modern turboprop.

Comment: _"Besides some cargo, passenger and tourism Airships there's one company that focuses on the super-rich by selling what are essentially flying super-yachts."_ You mean, like [Airlander](https://www.hybridairvehicles.com)?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit yes similar to Airlander or other modern Airships.

Comment: If you're going to do airships, please, please make them big enough.  Everyone has these things with balloons only about as big as the hulls.  1000 cubic feet of hydrogen lifts only about 60 pounds.  That means you probably need about a 15 foot diameter balloon just to lift **you**.  Your ship is going to be mostly balloon with a relatively small cargo area.

Comment: You can't get on or off most seagoing yachts without stopping them unless they are big enough to support a helipad. And yet people still use them. How important really is the ability to drop off and take on passengers in flight?

Comment: If you do need to drop off or retrieve passengers and cargo, you can go to any large open space. You don't need a mooring mast if the airship has enough thrust to hold its station in the wind and sufficient control (computer-assisted) to do so steadily. You could even hover on top of a tall building if the wind is not too strong.

Comment: Getting out is easy, but getting back means being under power such that you exceed the flight speed of the airship.  How will you judge the best answer?  What makes a rocketeer-style rocket pack more-or-less better than bungee jumping?  Without your judging criteria, this question is POB.

Comment: @JBH one problem I have with this site is how quickly people think it's a purely opinion based idea. Do I need to explain that using an idea of a working external elevator on an airship is a better idea than having to guide an ultralight into a miniature hangar when the super rich are likely going to need to sacrifice a seat for a pilot capable of flying it in? But an elevator already doesn't live up to the full solution as you can't exit while moving (unless you do one of those aerial exits but those aren't comfortable and require a lot of space).

Comment: From SE's pure perspective, nearly all ideas on this site are opinion-based, who has "expert experience" in magic?  it's why we've adopted an [alternative interpretation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6436#6437).  However, since we cannot change the SE-regulated text, we're constantly fighting the pure SE interpretation of "opinion-based."  (A lot of us would simply do away with it if we could... but we can't.)  My point is, POB here means you, the OP, must explain your judging criteria.  If we can't tell how you'll judge the answers, the question is POB.

Comment: @JBH an almost kneejerk reaction later I see how it can improve the answers. It remains tough criteria though. Example: comfort+luggage/passenger cap+privacy. An UltraLight (UL) has more comfort when a pilot flies, but at the cost of privacy and capacity. It depends on the UL's size and other features how much privacy is lost and how important the lost capacity is. When I work (with a group) on designing a new wheelchair for example we have to brainstorm and assign points to each idea but eventually look on a case-by-case basis what's useable. I tend to use the same approach here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A detachable, considerably smaller airship.

It will use gas of the overlord to offset most of the weight being lowered, minus a small amount which will allow for a mostly controlled descent. For safety (and a means to return), a cable will be attached between the two and an electric winch will be used to retrieve the smaller airship, along with any extra goods which may have been acquired.

Upon redocking, there wouldn't really need to be much need to equalize the gas until the next load is taken off (presumably of differing weight, and therefore, gas will need to be added/removed).

Edit: I guess I should have pointed out that the cable is also a means of equalizing gas so that the smaller balloon can remain on the ground if need be, or extra gas can be pushed to it to make the winch's job easier.

Comment: A detachable, considerably smaller airship. = A helicopter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure airship is the term for lighter-than-air aircraft. Helicopters fly by beating the world around them in to tenuous submission.

Comment: heli as idea for a smaller airship (not considering your definition).  Airships need much space, and aren't so manouvreable, so i thought it'd be a good 'smaller airship'. If you integrate that in your definition i'd write as solely answer

Comment: Good idea. Gets me thinking of some Heavier Than Air (HTA) Airships that use surfaces and speed to fly but require little speed to do it. A small one could function as an ultra-light aircraft capable of overtaking the overlord while needing little area to land on (with short-term VTOL almost none). Have two on the top, as below would likely be harder to land it, and you have one for the crew and one for the owners. A car would still need to be landed by the overlord but you can have a crewmember drive it while you land on a helipad perhaps...

Comment: If you think helicopter is a viable answer, then feel free to post it! I think a helicopter adds too much complexity (needs lots of extra fuel, maintenance, needs a pilot, initial cost, dangers of spinning blades around a balloon, difficult of recovering, etc) for being an answer. The simplicity of using another airship is that most of your materials are already there and you have experience in the maintenance of it.

Comment: @ColonelPanic I just want to point out that any viable flying machine, airships included, are equally as costly and complex as a helicopter. Airships themselves, even in sci-fi future, require fuel, maintenance, pilots, and more. The "considerably smaller" part is a slight issue - look at how large a typical hot air balloon has to be just to lift a couple of passengers and a basket

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of an ultralight or microlight for ferrying people - basically a wing and a small 2-stroke connected to a propeller would be sufficient for one or two people on day to day excursions - popping to the local town to purchase food for the next few days for example.

Comment: @automaton while true, Airships seem generally very low-maintenance and lack vulnerabilities that helicopters for example has. Also a Hot air balloon is about as similar to other Airships as a first world war biplane to a jet airliner. Theres some comparisons but in reality they arent very similar. Especially a HTA hybrid airship would require a lot less volume.

Comment: @automaton What Demigan said. Also, sure, everything requires maintenance, but your mother ship's mechanics will be able to work on the landing ship. Same with having the same fuel and pilots. And to emphasize Demigan's point: helicopters require hellamaintenance. Also, helium >> hot air in terms of lift per unit volume.

Comment: @ColonelPanic And by extension, when helicopter rotors fail, the world around them is so confused it lets them stay up for a bit. ([Autorotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorotation) is fascinating and strange)

Comment: @ColonelPanic (and Demigan, but I can only tag one) 
Ah, I was assuming that a mini airship would require a similar volume to that of a hot-air balloon. I guess because I've never seen a mini airship implemented irl, I just assumed that was the case. Yes, hellamaintenance indeed xD

Comment: This sounds like a spy basket (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy_basket) but with separate gas bags on the basket itself. I note that these were used in flight to direct the airship but not to drop off or retrieve crew from the ground.

Comment: If you're airship is travelling at 130 km/h and you don't want to make a stop for groceries then whoever makes the shopping needs to catch you up then. Assuming getting to a shop that you are passing by, making the purchase and getting back to a cruising height and speed takes 3 hours (you need to land somewhere and then get from there to the shop and back, finally take off again), during that time your mother airship is 400 km away. Whatever solution you use it has to be able to catch up. Smaller airship, even twice as fast (unlikely!), would need another 3 hours to get back to mother.

Answer (score 69):

**Jetpacks!**

[image: sweet sweet sweeeeet poster for the movie Rocketeer]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rocketeer_(film)

If you are going to have airships, you need jetpacks.  I can picture the crewman spotting the grocery coming into view below as he is shaving.  He straps on his pack and tumbles backwards off of the airship into free fall, zipping his pants and buttoning his shirt as he falls.  Shaving cream remnants blow upwards off of his face.   He turns his jets on full blast 10 yards above the ground, runs into the grocery and grabs a 12-pack of [Moxie](https://www.drinkmoxie.com/home), pays with a single silver coin, then back outside and blasting off to catch up with the airship receding away.

Comment: Wish I could give this+2

Comment: This wins due to the Rule of Cool.

Comment: @Renan I think there are more practical solutions, but I'm upvoting sheerly because Rule of Cool =)

Comment: Preposterous. What self-respecting airshipman with a jetpack would be using shaving cream? Think man!

Comment: +1 for the Moxie reference! Slight problem; how does he button his shirt over his jetpack?

Comment: @chif-ii Jetpack pants, of course

Comment: Moxie is still available in the Northeastern US.  I've tried it.  Takes a little getting used to but not bad.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1382/)

Answer (score 30):

## Skycrane

[image]

As long as you have lifting power, there is no reason that you can't just pick up and lower a large, comfortable elevator box (doesn't have to be shaped like a house).

If you want to keep moving while dropping someone off, why not just replace the elevator box with something with wheels?

[image]

Comment: +1 for fitting well into the flavor of an airship-driven future. Unconventional but viable, and a little zany too

Comment: How does the helicopter get close to the airship without ripping it open with the propellers? Is there a landing pad on top of the airship?

Comment: @JohnLocke I guess I was unclear, the crane is lowered directly from the airship. Its just that the real-world examples all involve helicopters; not many people are doing blimp lifts these days.

Comment: @kingledion Ok, your helicopter pictures made me think you were using a helicopter.

Comment: @JohnLocke also there is the option to attach hooks above the prophub that the airship will hook on to, the engine is shut down and then the heli gets reeled in.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Were on the helicopter does it hook on to? If it hooks onto the underside, the helicopter will be handling upside down as you reel it in.

Comment: @JohnLocke a hook above the propellor, it's the ideal place because that is also above the Center of Mass of the heli

Comment: @ratchetfreakAt 530 gallons of fuel being burned and hour, and at approximately 7lbs per gallon, you have to bring a lot of extra fuel with you in that airship or every time you fairy something, you had best be replenishing your fuel. Although I guess since you're lugging around an extra 17,000 lbs of weight with the skycrane, the amount of ballasting when your helicopter takes off and lands will make these other problems seem trivial.... I think the heli was only to demonstrate a winch (agreed its confusing), and isn't a viable solution.

Comment: This works exactly as depicted for a helicarrier.  I now want a personal helicarrier with a sky crane.

Comment: @JohnLocke: Note that airships are generally enormous, so there's no reason you couldn't support a fully enclosed helipad with retractable floor.  You'd be very far away from the envelope and there would be no serious risk.

Answer (score 21):

Small landing pad on top of airship, used by a conventional helicopter, flying cars, or drones for deliveries. In fact, groceries can be delivered by drone straight to the receiving hatch in the main gondola.

Also, the USS Akron that you mentioned could launch and retrieve airplanes. Modern electronics should make this process a lot safer and smoother.

Comment: I really like the drone idea for groceries and other supplies. Much lighter than an airplane if you don't need to send people down.

Comment: Actually a drone could also carry people up and down too. https://www.engadget.com/2016/01/06/184-delivery-drone-for-people/

Comment: It doesn't even need to be on the top of the airship -- you could have a landing/cargo bay on virtually any horizontal surface.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest an elevator without a shaft, i.e., a sort of cable car or gondola.  Perhaps the entire "cabin" descends from the airframe on a cable, and serves as an anchor while it sits on the ground.  It might get a bit unnerving in high winds, so an alternative would be to drop a weighted anchor first, then have the cabin or a part of the cabin descent along the already-taut cable.

The balloon will continue to float overhead, and the only real risk of harm is if other balloons are parked too close together (they might crash into one another in the wind).  I am assuming you have figured out a solution for dangerous weather -- either descending the entire airship to ground level and securing it, or perhaps flying high above the weather.

If the cable car is large enough, it could include parking space for the owner's supercar and comfortable seating for his guests.

Comment: This would be improved if you add a picture from the movie "Filibus: The Mysterious Pirate of the Skies." It's in the public domain.

Comment: I don't know it.  Feel free to make an edit.

Answer (score 2):

If your modern day analogue is the yacht, I would think they would dock at marina like area.  Unlike cars, which are mandated by local governments to have extra space for parking, (typically) no such laws apply to yachts having public mooring.  Instead (mostly) private enterprises dedicate space that caters to the specific needs of the vehicle, and their super rich owners.

If, however, your airships are as common as cars, then you would need government intervention and infrastructure investment in order to prevent utter chaos in the skies.

You also asked about the physical considerations.  I can envision a system similar to what was used back when airships were common.  They were typically tethered to a spire which could raise and lower the ship mechanically.  But if we are envisioning a marina analogue, I would imagine a tower more than a tether.  One that had an interior so as to protect the fliers from the elements.  That interior would have a covered landing platform that could extend to the airship door.  It would also have the ability to dock several "layers" of airships.  Each story of the tower could contain 4 or so airships along it's circumference.  This would be an efficient use of vertical space for precious land.

The tower would likely have maintenance facilities, and a "dry dock" if longer term repairs are needed.  This means it would likely have a way to bring an airship down to ground level, where there is separate facilities for major work.  I envision crane like arms extending from the center of the tower that extend out past the spaces of the currently docked airship.  The airship tethers it's nose to it, and then the arm moves the ship to it's appointed dock, or even to the ground for long term storage or decommissioning.  Each tower might only have 2 or 3 cranes that can move up and down to different levels as well as extend its arm our.  Or maybe there is one crane on each level, servicing that level only.

Answer (score 2):

A small light aircraft could land or take off from the top of the airship.  Unless the airship is in bumpy air, the airship's environment will be ideal for landing.  This is especially true if the airship is running under power.  This will create a headwind if you land tail to bow.  That's ideal for landing and taking off.

You can keep the landing craft pretty light since it doesn't need a lot of fuel or speed.  A Cessna 152 or a smaller Piper would work fine.  Larger aircraft that can hold more people/cargo would work as well.

Actually you don't really need the headwind for taking off if you don't mind a bit of excitement if the aircraft does not reach flying speed (higher than the stall speed) by the time it gets to the bow of the airship.  The aircraft will quickly achieve the proper speed as it falls.  Thus, cargo runs can just be taxied off the side.  I wouldn't recommend this for most passengers.

Some zeppelins had hooks under them to catch and release a single aircraft that had the proper attachment and reinforcement to the top of the aircraft.  That would fail your "comfortable" requirement and hooking was a bit of a tricky maneuver.

There were plans, before airships fell out of favor, to create flying aircraft carriers.  If they could build those pre-WWII, we can build them today.  The only thing that makes it trickier is that modern aircraft generally hive a higher stall speed than the older aircraft.

Comment: they were more than plans. They build 2 of them, carrying 5 aircraft maximum each (although 3 was more practical).

Comment: @Demigan, yeah I thought so but I couldn't remember it enough to put in my answer.

Comment: If you look at the OP you can see a link to the USS Achron, which was one of the airborne carriers.

Answer (score 2):

You want one or two ultralight vehicles. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aviation

You have a huge hull filled with gas. On many of the old dirigibles, parts of the passenger cabin and often the entire crew cabin were built inside the hull. You can absolutely build a small hangar inside from which to launch and land your ultralight flyers. Many types of ultralights have takeoff and landing roll distances of around 50 feet.

The aerodynamics of flying into a closed hangar for landing could be interesting, I don't understand enough about that to judge, but if this part works out, you have a convenient method, you can field different types and sizes for different purposes, you can stored them inside your hull and have space there for refueling and repairs as well.

Comment: For takeoff you might use a drop ramp, just long enough for an ultralight to get above stall speed.  As noted in other answers, such a launch method would be, well, quite exciting.

Comment: Or you could just use a hook that lowers the ultralight (with engine running) out of the hanger, which then detaches and flies off.  For retrieval the ultralight flies up under the hook, climbs slightly to attach, and is winched in, turning off the engine as it enters. This is exactly how aircraft launch and retreival [worked in the Akron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Akron_(ZRS-4)) (see the middle of the "Technical Descripton" section).

Comment: The link to the Acron is actually very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

At least one US Navy blimp had an extendable hook that a small plane could fly up to, engage, then get hauled up inside. No need to invent anything more complicated.

Bush pilots fly in circles and lower a rope when delivering goods in the rain forest (where there are no runways). Centripetal force keeps the bottom of the rope relatively stationary allowing items to be placed in a bucket attached to the end of the rope. Scale it up a bit to accommodate passengers.

It isn't particularly comfortable, but the military worked out a system wherein a passing aircraft snags a cable lofted by balloon. The person embarking the airplane gets yanked aloft then winched inside.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7q3MnJBxrw
Disney's UP movie style.  Have a homing device aboard, and your airship comes and pickups you up.

[image]

http://www.tarproductions.com John Freis, 51, ties 170 helium balloons to his lawn chair (in a sophisticated manner, of course) and flies up to 12,400 ft, traveling 46 miles in almost 4 hours. He had a parachute, oxygen, GPS, ballast and a BB gun.

https://youtu.be/6Hp2Ys3lHSc?t=682

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a small bay with powered hangliders with extra glass panes to protect from wind could fill the same function as a dingy would today?

Pick one add, some comfort improvements. A large airship could have many of varying sizes etc.

Electric engines should help reduce noise too.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_hang_glider

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_trike

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultralight_aviation

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that airships are shaped much like sausages.
Could an airship not have a large "Keel" that could contain an elevator and other access structures.

Dynamic position control similar to that used by floating oil platforms could allow the keel to touch down and the crew could step off onto the ground and roll on any livestock, farm goods or grand pianos that were required.

Answer (score 0):

Why not land?   Submarines increase and decrease their buoyancy by taking on water.  I suspect you could do the same with the durable.  My thought would be to pump the Helium into to tanks while filling an inner bladder with air from outside. It would decrease the lift, and the airship could land while preserving lifting gas.

Comment: Because Airships are big and landing might not be an option. Imagine going to New York and the only place to land is an airfield or a very large field likely outside of the city. While practical, its not the place you want to park your flying home. Assuming the airfield has a space where the airship isnt in the way ofcourse.

Comment: NY is easy: top of the ESB is a mooring tower but it was only used once.

Comment: @Mazura, it was only used once for a very good reason: the winds make docking extremely hazardous.

Comment: Even a small airship needs a big landing field.  The Goodyear blimps require an area 150+ meters across, and they're the airborne equivalent of a small travel trailer.  A "flying super-yacht" would be something comparable to the *USS Los Angeles* or the *Graf Zeppelin*, 200-250 meters long and needing about 500 meters of landing field.  To put it in the context of New York, Kennedy International could park maybe a dozen airships.